# How to pass an array to a script in an underscore template?

Tags: json, underscore.js

I am trying to pass an array of filenames into a template such that a var will then have access to the array. This is so my page doesn't have to do an AJAX request after page load. From my express route, I render the template:

```
var a = ['a.jpg','b.jpg','c.jpg'];
res.render('clean', {images: a});
```

In my template:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var images = <%- JSON.stringify(images) %>;
</script>
```

What I would expect:

```
var images = ["a.jpg", "b.jpg", "c.jpeg"];
```

What I get:

```
var images = [&quot;a.jpg&quot;,&quot;b.jpg&quot;,&quot;c.jpg&quot;];
```

I've tried doing the stringify in routing code instead of the template, but same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking the [documentation](http://underscorejs.org/#template), you can read:

> Template functions can both interpolate values, using <%= … %>, as
>   well as execute arbitrary JavaScript code, with <% … %>. If you wish
>   to interpolate a value, and have it be HTML-escaped, use <%- … %>.

You're using `<%-` therefore the output is HTML escaped. I suggest you use `<%=` to avoid the problem.

Hope it helps.

```js
// Your current code.
var templFnc = _.template('var images = <%- JSON.stringify(images) %>');

console.log(templFnc({
  images: ["a.jpg", "b.jpg", "c.jpeg"]
}));

// Code using <%= instead of <%-
var templFnc = _.template('var images = <%= JSON.stringify(images) %>');

console.log(templFnc({
  images: ["a.jpg", "b.jpg", "c.jpeg"]
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore.js"></script>
```